# Web scraping string from span (no id) contained within div class

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to scrape a website
I had try scrape memory storage in website (https://www.amazon.in/OnePlus-Mirror-Black-64GB-Memory/dp/B0756Z43QS?tag=googinhydr18418-21&tag=googinkenshoo-21&ascsubtag=aee9a916-6acd-4409-92ca-3bdbeb549f80) with this code

```
#Specifying the url for desired website to be scrapped
url <- "https://www.amazon.in/OnePlus-Mirror-Black-64GB-Memory/dp/B0756Z43QS?tag=googinhydr18418-21&tag=googinkenshoo-21&ascsubtag=aee9a916-6acd-4409-92ca-3bdbeb549f80"
#Reading the html content from Amazon
webpage <- read_html(url)
html_nodes(webpage, "span.a-size-base") %>% 
    html_text()
```

But the result have many information. How i can scape only "64 GB" from this web.
Many tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use -

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://www.amazon.in/OnePlus-Mirror-Black-64GB-Memory/dp/B0756Z43QS?tag=googinhydr18418-21&tag=googinkenshoo-21&ascsubtag=aee9a916-6acd-4409-92ca-3bdbeb549f80"
#Reading the html content from Amazon
webpage <- read_html(url)

webpage %>%
  html_nodes("td.a-span9") %>% 
  html_text() %>%
  trimws() %>%
  toString() %>%
  stringr::str_extract('\\d+ GB')

#[1] "64 GB"
```

Comment: Tks @Ronak Shah. Is there a way to use html_nodes() to extract exactly "64 GB" instead of using get all text in "td.a-span9" and str_extract?

Comment: Check output of `webpage %>% html_nodes("td.a-span9")` the 5 values are exactly the same with no difference in them so I don't think we can exactly get "64 GB" directly.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like one of those rare occasions where xpath, for web-scraping, is useful. You can target the `Memory Storage Capacity` text and then move to the sibling `td`. Hopefully, somewhat more robust should attributes change.

If you are going to use regex, you might as well not make a request and just extract is from the url direct.

```
library(magrittr)
library(rvest)

value <- read_html("https://www.amazon.in/OnePlus-Mirror-Black-64GB-Memory/dp/B0756Z43QS?tag=googinhydr18418-21&tag=googinkenshoo-21&ascsubtag=aee9a916-6acd-4409-92ca-3bdbeb549f80") %>%
  html_node(xpath = "//*[@id='productOverview_feature_div']//span[text()='Memory Storage Capacity']/parent::td/following-sibling::td/span") %>%
  html_text()
```

---

`Memory Storage` is in a child `span`. In order to get to the adjacent `td` child `span` text (64GB) , one needs to move up the DOM to the parent `td`, of the `span` where target text found, and across to the next `td`, then down into the child `span`.

Comment: Tks @QHarr. I understand "//*@id='productOverview_feature_div']//span[text()='Memory Storage Capacity']" but don't know "/parent::td/following-sibling::td/span". Can u explain for me.

Comment: Memory Storage is in a child span. In order to get to the adjacent td child span text (64GB) , one needs to move up the DOM to the parent td, of the span where target text found, and across to the next td, then down into the child span.